# Do I Need to Sign Up With iTunes Connect Before Apple Serves Test iAds?

Tags: ios, iad

I think I have a correct implementation but in the simulator the only delegate method that gets called is `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:`. It would seem that I'm contacting the iAd server properly, but it is consistently returning `The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable` or `The operation couldn’t be completed. Application has iAd Network configuration error`.

I'm using the 4.5 SDK against the iOS 6 simulator if that matters. I've checked over the code (which is hideously too long to post), and all seems correct -- that the delegate method is being called is a good sign -- but the latter error message makes me suspect this might be about the app not being registered with iTunes Connect.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have the same problem only on iOS 6 simulator. On 4.3 and 5.0 everything seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered after watching this for quite a while that Apple serves up a number of errors, sometimes sequentially and often on startup. That meant that a number of errors were being reported regarding configuration or network unavailability that were simply test errors to make sure my code handled the errors correctly. The biggest issue here is that it can take 90-120 seconds before a banner is served with no error!

So with all the scary messages, I was getting no "your code is working fine, I'm just complaining to tweak you" feedback. It would be great if Apple served a success fir the first couple of banners so you could quickly check if your layout was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that something in my wireless network configuration is causing these errors. When I switched to 3G I get the banner almost instantly. And when I switch back to wireless, I don't get the error (as frequently at least). Not a high enough priority to hunt down the problem in the network config - it's just nice to know my code is working.